# GlobalScope | Kotlin | Передача данных между потоками

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, recyclerviewadapter

Есть fragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val activity = Activity("/team/1261", "https://tl.rulate.ru")

    GlobalScope.launch { activity.getMainRecommended() } <--- Вот тут

    val _adapter = DataAdapter()
    _adapter.set(activity.getData())

    val _layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? =
        LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

    recyclerRecommended.apply {
        layoutManager = _layoutManager
        adapter = _adapter
    }
}
```

В нем вызвается второй поток и там парсится страница.
В классе parser.Activity:

```
fun getMainRecommended() {
    try {
        val dom = init()

        val bookList = dom.select("ul.search-results li")

        for (book in bookList) {
            val title = book.select("p.book-tooltip a").text()
            val link = book.select("p.book-tooltip a").attr("href")
            val image = book.select("div.th img").attr("src")

            val _book = Book()
            _book.translate_title = title
            _book.link = prefix + link
            _book.image = prefix + image

            dataList.add(_book)
        }

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            log("Parser finished")

        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {

    }
}
```

Все работает правильно, но я не понимаю, как мне передать данные в основной поток, чтобы потом передать лист в адаптер?

Comment: если фрагмент выполняет один и тот же запрос, логично перенести его в onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил не совсем так, как задумывал, но все работает.

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val activity = Activity("/...", "https://...")

    val myService: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)

    val result = myService.submit(Callable<MutableList<Book>> {
        activity.getMainRecommended()
    })

    val _adapter = DataAdapter()
    _adapter.set(result.get())

    val _layoutManager: LinearLayoutManager? =
        LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

    recyclerRecommended.apply {
        layoutManager = _layoutManager
        adapter = _adapter
    }
```

Использовал Callable и получаю из функции тип MutableList. **Все работает!**

---

### ОБНОВЛЕНО 10.19.20

Использовал более правильный(моё мнение) способ:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
    //Выполняю нужный мне код. Например, заполняю RecyclerView или т.п.
}
```